# How to check if a queen is under attack in Nqueens

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, depth-first-search, n-queens

My college assignment requires me to submit the solution to the 8queens problem using depth first search.
I am having trouble understanding how to check if the queens are under attack.
Also we maybe required to represent it in a 8 x 8 array, current implementations I've seen only use one array.
If someone could explain to me how it works it will be much appreciated!

I've seen other solutions but its all very vague to me. I've also read through Djikstra's explanation of it but I am still very lost.
It's all one array, adding to much of the confusion.

Comment: Two queens are under attack if (1) they share the same row; (2) they share the same column; or (3) they share the same diagonal.

Comment: Another hint: Diagonals have a constant sum (x+y) or difference (x-y) of their coordinates.

Comment: So it means that `x1 == x2 || y1 == y2 || x1-y1 == x2-y2 || x1+y1 == x2+y2`.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting confused since most of the time its all j or k or something else. uncommented code does not help lol. Does this apply if I am using 2d arrays as well? Since I've seen it implemented like that in 1d arrays.

Comment: @mefiz: usually one implements it on a 1d array, since the column (or row) is implied by the index, and therefore one can not place two queens on the same column/row, since an index can only contain one value.

Comment: Ah I see. @Willem Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Each queen have a position on the board that can be represented as (X,Y).

Given two Queen : Queen#1 (X1, Y1) and Queen#2 (X2, Y2)

Given a board of sixe 8x8

A queen can attack another if :

- they are on the same line : X1 = X2
- they are on the same column : Y1 = Y2
- they are on the same diagonal : X1-Y1 = X2-Y2 or X1+Y1 = X2+Y2